# How can I shuffle items to each other. Just using CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, css-selectors

I am trying to shuffle 1st item with 2nd item, 3rd item with 4th item and 5th item with 6th item...and so on.

**Condition : Items are not fixed. It can be more than 6.**

**Existing scenario**
[image]

**Expected Result**
[image]

Comment: You will almost certainly need Javascript for this to be done dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your items have the same height (as on your picture), you might shift even items upwards, odd ones downwards, and here you are:

```css
li {
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: .25em 0;
  background: #6df;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  transform: translateY(calc(100% + .25em));
}

li:nth-child(even) {
  transform: translateY(calc(-100% - .25em));
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Awesome Man, Thanks. Everyone said this is not possible with pure CSS even experts. You have deep and great knowledge.

Comment: It passes when all items content is one line, But if any of them content will go 4 to 5 line or more than that, than it will fail.

Comment: @Mak0619, my answer starts with `If your items have the same height (as on your picture)`. They must be **the same height**, otherwise you need another approach.

Comment: I Saw your answer, Just asking if it possible, we can fix dynamic height with this approach or any.